# R - for loop - using values in previous row

Tags: r, for-loop, lag

create a new column in R, using timepoints corresponding to a rating in another column.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Stimulus   Subject   Attribute   Timepoint   Complexity   Start   End   Duration                         
   1               1        creamy          t1                  2             t1       t5       4

Comment: Please update your post by editing

Comment: Something you should consider, especially when using manual row offsets or lags: from the fields you have there, it is most likely necessary to do this *per group*, so that you do not inadvertently update/choose data from one `Subject` based on properties in another. I know this has nothing to do with your literal question, but it looks like it might be appropriate; without it (if it is necessary), you may get either (1) really confusing results, or (2) realistic-looking but incorrect results.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was likely, I just wanted to start somewhere. Can you help with what I'm tryin to do, I did not have any luck with the other answer?

Comment: Please post the *whole* output from `dput`, unaltered, unabridged; in this case, `Structure` is not right, and it is lacking at least `))` (and `class` information, if not more). If you cut it out intending to limit the data, good on you, but please do that to the data inside of `dput`; that is, `dput(x[,1:4])`. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidyverse solution:

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
dataframe.df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint = as.numeric(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", Timepoint))) %>% 
  group_by(Replicate, Stimulus, Subject) %>% 
  mutate(start_end_time = ifelse(Timepoint != max(Timepoint), min(Timepoint), max(Timepoint))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you. But in the new variable the values are all t.77. The complexity rating can vary between 1 and 9

Comment: @Niamh what is the data type of the Complexity rating vector?

Comment: Numeric data. sorry not sure exactly what you mean. So I was to know for example, the Timepoint when a complexity rating (1-9) started and the Timepoint when it finished (changing to a new rating from 1-9), there are 18 subjects, 3 replicates and 5 stimuli

Comment: @Niamh you need to post a reusable example.

Comment: how do I do that? I couldn't copy paste to the comment?

Comment: Use `dput(head(dataframe.df))` and copy and paste the result from the console to your question.

Comment: OK great , that's there now. I was trying to copy paste to comments.

Comment: 1. your timepoint variable is of character type (its prefexied with a "t") so arithmetic operations won't work until it is coerced to be of a numeric type.

Comment: 2. Your dataframe.df is actually a list so this too needs to be coerced to a data.frame

Comment: 3. Your question is unclear about whether or not your results need to be grouped by categories.

Comment: Above is what was returned. It looks like it is still not telling start_end times. It needs to be grouped by replicate, stimulus and subject.

Comment: @Niamh please see the edited solution above.

Comment: Thank you @hello_friend, the start time and end time variables are not visible

Comment: you need to save the result of the function into a new variable using the `<-` operator. If you look at the console output currently you will see the result. Please upvote and accept my solution if it has done what you require.

Comment: Yes I see it, ` with 20,604 more rows, and 2 more variables: start_time <dbl>,
#   end_time <dbl>` , will save now

Comment: @Niamh please see edited solution I provided above to combine start_time and end_time into a single vector

Comment: Thank you so much, I am just trying to make sure I have done it correctly and if it has done what I wanted.

Comment: the last code you gave me worked, now I would like to find out the duration of each complexity rating (difference between start_time and end_time, for each subject on each attribute, stimulus and replicate. Can you help again please?

Comment: @Niamh Please ask another question and post a link to it so I may answer it there.

Comment: Will do thank you. Looks like I have to wait 24 hours before I can ask a new question.